# updating angular-cli 1.0.0-beta 28.3 to @angular/cli@latest failed

Tags: angular, version, angular-cli, updates

I have a problem with updating angular/cli - even downgrading failed too.

I have a well working angular2 app which I updated to angular 4.4.1 today.
Everything works fine when I build the app for `--prod` and `--aot` under angular4.

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 6.9.5
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.1
@angular/common: 4.4.1
@angular/compiler: 4.4.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.1
@angular/core: 4.4.1
@angular/forms: 4.4.1
@angular/http: 4.4.1
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.1
@angular/platform-server: 4.4.1
@angular/router: 4.4.1
```

Now I wanted to **update** my angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.82.3 to the latest version of @angular/cli because my current version outside @angular was deprecated.

After `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` and `npm install --save-dev@angular/cli@latest` there where much warnings I solved with the information in this warnings regarding compatible versions of `webpack` as well as `node-libs-browser` as well as `file-loader`.

But it failed again because of this error:

```
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[...]
@ ./src/app/main/main.component.css 6:12782-12818
@ ./src/app/main/main.component.ts
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

It seemed that the package-manager search for all my jpegs in css. under the component of this css (in folder `assets`) and not under the folder `src` (assets).
Now I had downgrade the verion of cli to `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3` again and installed the webpack version 2.2.0 in course of a new warning.

But there are even a new error:

```
ERROR in ng:///C:/Daten/example/project/src/app/blog-entry/blog-entry.component.html (27,36): Property 'blog_text' does not exist on type 'Blogs'.
```

under this current version-set:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 6.9.5
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.1
@angular/common: 4.4.1
@angular/compiler: 4.4.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.1
@angular/core: 4.4.1
@angular/forms: 4.4.1
@angular/http: 4.4.1
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.1
@angular/platform-server: 4.4.1
@angular/router: 4.4.1
@angular/cli: 1.4.2
```

In this setup all works without `ng build --prod --aot` and thats my problem.
I figured out to remove @angular/cli with `npm uninstall --save @angular/cli`.

But its the same error like above plus an error by `ng version`:
Cannot find module `'C:\Daten\example\project\node_modules\@angular\cli\package.json'`

I hope there is anyone to give me a solution approach for solving this problem because I dont can build my app with the current problem.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you follow [these exact steps](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli) when updating the CLI? You may be better off building a new project with the latest CLI, and copying your code to that. It could save you a ton of time rather than dealing with this troubleshooting.

Comment: Totally agree build new project and compare them. And frankly probably nobody know exactly what you need to do in your project to update to angular cli :-)

Comment: thank you very much for your answers, I think I have to go this way because there are still errors in configuration

Answer (score 0):

I don't rely on the update docs. This is what worked for me in the past:

```
npm uninstall angular-cli -g
npm cache clear
npm install @angular/cli -g

ng new myProjectName
```

Replace the content of the src dir in in the generated project with what you have in the existing one.

Copy your assets dir (if any) into the newly generated project

If you use third-party libs, update the styles and scripts properties in your newly generated .angular-cli.json.

If you've installed additional packages manually in your existing project, update package.json in the newly generated project and run npm install.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have done any step, but there is still the error:npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: Most likely this is not an error - it just can't find some optional dependency. It tells you that fsevents was created for Mac OS, but you run on windows.  you may also try to install the latest version of Node.js to see if this warning will disappear.

Comment: thank you again for your support! There are many red errors which refer to (relative path: .src/app/main/assets)...main here is an component, but the asset dir is directly under `src` --> this message is given:: Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /using description file: .../package.json

Comment: assets should be under src

Comment: yes, that´s correct. the asset folder is under the src folder. but the error means, that the compiler looks at the asset folder under the affected (css) component folder. do you have an idea which configuration can route the compiler so wrong, because the folder structure as well as css entry is correct e.g. background: url("./assets/img/example.jpg") - Thank you very much for your support, this should be the last step for successful running of ng serve as ng build --prod --aot

Comment: It looks like an issue with your webpack. Are you sure you have the latest Angular CLI? Does 'ng --version' print CLI 1.4.2? 
Also, if you had package-lock.json in your project, remove it an reinstall.

Comment: Yes ng --version show me a @angular/cli: 1.4.2., package-lock.json isn´t there.your right, that the webpack probably is the problem because of the wrong routing to asset folder. @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts -->[C:\Daten\Website_Angular_new \example\src\app\main\assets\img\seaside.jpg.ts] -->the compiler search for assets in component folder.